# Is it possible to change elements of a webpage depending on specfic XML values?

Tags: jquery, html, xml

Im trying to test this but Im having issues.

Can I use jquery to check a value in an xml file and depending on that value (true/false) new divs will be shown and others will be hidden.

eg. If the xml has a tag  with a True inside it, jquery checks this and swapa out a default div with a new "lightOne" div.

Edit: I am unable to edit the xml, only read from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "url.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (data) {
            var txt = $(data).find('something').text(); 
            // 'something' is your xml tag
               if (txt === 'true') {
                  // create your div
               } 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot! This is perfect :D I didnt think to use ajax.

Comment: I was just wondering, how would you make the jquery check for a change in the xml? So if a true value is made false in the xml, the jquery can see this instantly?